# Apache shiro web application index page as default page

Tags: java, web-applications, web.xml, servlet-filters, shiro

I am new to Apache Shiro web application development. I have a index.html in my web directory which inturn as a link to login.htm
I want the index.html to be my default page, i.e, when url is like : 

    `localhost:8080/myapp/`

or

    `localhost:8080/myapp/index.html`


It should show index.html
How can I prevent shiro filter with url pattern /*. I mean shiro must not filter or process the index.html.
Now it keeps on redirecting to login.htm because of obivious reason as it is configured usually in web.xml and shiro.ini

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set index.html as welcome-file in web.xml

web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

In shiro.ini allow anonymous users for your index.html URL. 
Give an entry for index.html before your /* entry

```
[urls]

/index.html = anon
/*={your mapping}
```